# window addEventListener keydown not firing

Tags: javascript, function, window, addeventlistener, keydown

I'm making the 2048 game, but the window.addEventListener("keydown", handleInput, {once:true}); does not firing. But if I console.log(e.key), I get the message that I pressed the button (ArrowUp, -Down and os on), but the tile does not move. Can anyone help please?

This is the index.js file that contains the eventlistener.

```
import Grid from "./grid.js";
import Tile from "./tile.js";

const gameBoard = document.getElementById('game-board');
const grid = new Grid(gameBoard);

grid.randomEmptyCell().tile = new Tile(gameBoard);
grid.randomEmptyCell().tile = new Tile(gameBoard);
setupInput();

function setupInput() {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleInput, { once: true });
}

async function handleInput(e) {
  console.log(e.key);
  switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowUp":
      if(!canMoveUp()) {
        setupInput();
        return;
      }
      await moveUp()
      break
    case "ArrowDown":
      if(!canMoveDown()) {
        setupInput();
        return;
      }
      await moveDown()
      break
    case "ArrowLeft":
      if(!canMoveLeft()) {
        setupInput();
        return;
      }
      await moveLeft()
      break
    case "ArrowRight":
      if(!canMoveRight()) {
        setupInput();
        return;
      }
      await moveRight()
      break
    default:
      setupInput()
      return
  }

  grid.cells.forEach(cell => cell.merTiles());

  const newTile = new Tile(gameBoard);

  grid.randomEmptyCell().tile = newTile;

  if (!canMoveUp() && !canMoveDown() && !canMoveLeft() && !canMoveRight()) {
    newTile.waitForTransition(true).then(() => {
      alert("You lose!");
    });
  } return
  setupInput();
}

function moveUp() {
  return slideTiles(grid.cellsByColumn);
}

function moveDown() {
  return slideTiles(grid.cellsByColumn.map(column => [...column].reverse()));
}

function moveLeft() {
  return slideTiles(grid.cellsByRow);
}

function moveRight() {
  return slideTiles(grid.cellsByRow.map(row => [...row].reverse()));
}

function slideTiles(cells) {
  return Promise.all(
  cells.flatMap(group => {
    const promises = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < group.length; i++) {
      const cell = group[i];
      if (cell.tile == null) continue;
      let lastValidCell;
      for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        const moveToCell = group[j];
        if (!moveToCell.canAccept(cell.tile)) break;
        lastValidCell = moveToCell;
      }
      if (lastValidCell != null) {
        promises.push(cell.tile.waitForTransition());
        if (lastValidCell.tile != null) {
          lastValidCell.mergeTile = cell.tile;
        } else {
          lastValidCell.tile = cell.tile;
        }
        cell.tile = null;
      }
    }
    return promises;
  }));
}

function canMoveUp() {
  return canMove(grid.cellsByColumn);
}

function canMoveDown() {
  return canMove(grid.cellsByColumn.map(column => [...column].reverse()));
}

function canMoveLeft() {
  return canMove(grid.cellsByRow);
}

function canMoveRight() {
  return canMove(grid.cellsByRow.map(row => [...row].reverse()));
}

function canMove(cells) {
  return cells.some(group => {
    return group.some((cell, index) => {
      if (index === 0) return false;
      if (cell.tile == null) return false;
      const moveToCell = group[index - 1];
      return moveToCell.canAccept(cell.tile);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you log `e.keyCode` since that's what you're using in the `switch`?

Comment: If you get the log message then it *is* firing, it's just not doing what you expect.

Comment: Please reduce the code to a [mre].

Comment: Maybe it works `once: true` then stops?

Comment: I am using e.key, I tried to find the mistake and I forgot to write it back. But either if I log out the e.keyCode it gives the value of the button so it should not be the problem.

Comment: It is wotking now, I am not really sure what I did :D but thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

See mdn page:
[EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

A boolean value indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If true, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked. If not specified, defaults to false.

if you remove {once: true}, it will can work more than once.

Also one more thing, you use console.log(e.key) but you use e.keyCode in switch cases. On MDN, keyCodes are actually codes.[Code values for keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_code_values#code_values_on_windows)

so, you should either change your switch case conditions to e.key to use the same values: [Key values for keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values)

or change the case values from text to keyCode

Comment: Yes, I tried it as well but still does not work. If I log out the keyCode as suggested and it gives the value of the up,down,left and right keys. As the key does with words. Yeah, I actually use e.key, I just forgot to rewrite it. I am not really sure what I did but its working. :D I will read the pages you linked in here thank you very much.